# How can i delete an array localitie?

Tags: java, arrays, null

I have an array, i make the localities overwrite, but at the end of the array theres a "null"
Is there a way to make this null not be taking place in the array for future uses?

```
 public void overwriteArray(int num){        
        if(num > 0 && array != null && num <= array.length) {
           for(int i = num-1; i < array.length-1; i++) {
               array[i] = array[i+1];
        }    arrary[array.length-1] = null; // i want this null to be terminated              
     }
   }
```

I came up with making the array shorter, deleting the last localitie, but i dont know how, its okk my idea?
thanks!

Comment: You cannot make an array shorter since arrays are not dynamically resizable. Use an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change the length of an existing array to make it shorter (or longer).

If you are going to use bare arrays, then then only way to avoid leaving `null` references in the array is to allocate a new array with the correct (new) length, copy the elements and then use the new array in place of the old one.  You can do this directly using `new` and a `for` loop to copy the elements, or you can use `Arrays.copyOf(...)`, `Arrays.copyOfRange(...)` and/or `System.arraycopy(...)`.

There are two alternatives:

- The best one is to use a `List` of some kind instead of an array.  This is preferable in most cases since it makes your code a lot simpler.
- You could use a separate `int` variable to represent the number of non-null elements in the array.